# Access Element in Iframe with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I try to access an element via XPath, but it is not working somehow. The element is in an IFrame, could that be the reason?
If so, what do I need to do in order to be able to access it still?
Or might it be an issue, that I nested two html's (HTML Code Picture)? What would be a workaround for that?

The error message I get:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='oslist']/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Trzk.png)/tbody/tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7xrG.png)/td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7xrG.png)/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Trzk.png)/td/a"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 1.14 seconds

Java Code:

```
 @Test
 public void testGenerierter() throws Exception {

     driver.findElement(By.id("cmdSigOn")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("k278")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("k279")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.id("k332")).click();
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.switchTo().frame("1");

     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='oslist']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a"));
     driver.findElement(By.id("LogoutButton")).click();

}
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Trzk.png)

[XPath from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7xrG.png)

Comment: Can you provide the actual website address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys this is the Solution. i take the method with the Webelement

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("1")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

You are passing an integer, so double quotes are not required. And try to verify the correct iframe index number and your following xpath.

Comment: I have try,  but the same error. It doesnt find a frame with 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an exception on the xpath which means you are getting error on line `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='oslist']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a"));`

```
@Test
public void testGenerierter() throws Exception {

 driver.findElement(By.id("cmdSigOn")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("k278")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("k279")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("k332")).click();
 Thread.sleep(3000);
 driver.switchTo().frame(1);
   Thread.sleep(3000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("Give the Relative xpath here"));
 driver.findElement(By.id("LogoutButton")).click();
```

}

PS : Why are you using absolute xpath.Relative xpath is the best practice

Comment: I have try absolut and relativ path. The path generate Firefox with the plugin firepath. I have try absolut because i have separeted iframes

Comment: You can share the screenshot of the code on which you are finding xpath or the URL

Comment: I have adjusted my question with the Picture where i find the xpath